# Как раскодировать $GLOBALS['_1771282481_']=Array(base64_decode('Ym....

Tags: php, геокодирование, декомпиляция

Суть в чем: нашел на своем сайте залитый дор, в нем два закодированных `php` файла. Пробовал сам разобраться и раскодировать их, но ничего не выходит. Может кто поможет?
Буду очень благодарен, уж очень хочется их код посмотреть.

Файлы залил в архив http://chernivtsy.pp.ua/1.rar

Если не хотите, могу код сюда закинуть...

Comment: Это обфусцированный код PHP. Попробуйте его "подеобфусцировать" на всех известных деобфускаторах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Декомпилировал один файл.

По моему код обфусцирован без обратного восстановления, так что деобфускатор еще поискать нужно. Но ручками разбирается всё на раз.

http://ideone.com/F2il5j

Comment: Можете пожалуйста описать алгоритм действий по разбору обфуската? Что конкретно нужно сделать что бы его декодировать?

Comment: Тыщу лет прошло, но в целом всё просто - конец обфускации обычно сводится к какой-то инжектируемой строке куда-либо. Обычно это какой-нибудь `eval` и вместо него надо подставить `echo`.